# Changing leaflet basemaps with react buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I have two buttons and the idea is: when I click a button, it changes the `basemap` state. However, each time I click on the button to change the `basemap tilelayer`, I get

```
Error: Map container is already initialized.
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix this? My code is below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Initializing map');
    var map = L.map(ref.current).setView([53.9, -9.5], 10);
    setLeafletMap(map);

    const osm = L.tileLayer(
      'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
      {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 20,
      }
    );
      const aerial = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        {
          attribution:'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
        }
      );
        const basemapLayers = {
                'OSM': osm, 
                'Aerial': aerial
            };
        basemapLayers[selectedBasemap].addTo(map);
  }, [selectedBasemap]);
```

Comment: Once you do `setLeafletMap(map)`, then you have `leafletMap === map` on next tick.

Comment: Yes, I was failing on this vital piece of information - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you should avoid reinitializing your map everytime you click on a different button.

Here the "difficulty" with React functional components is that it may not be obvious where to store that map and its Tile Layers. A solution is to use a `useRef` hook, which you populate at the component instanciation with a `useEffect` hook that runs only once (i.e. with an empty dependency array `[]`).

Something in the lines of:

```
const leafletObjects = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  leafletObjects.current = {
    map: L.map(ref.current),
    basemapLayers: {
      OSM: L.tileLayer(osmUrlTemplate),
      Aerial: L.tileLayer(aerialUrlTemplate)
    }
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  leafletObjects.current.basemapLayers[selectedBasemap].addTo(leafletObjects.current.map);
}, [selectedBasemap]);
```

Note: I see that you also used a state hook to store your map. It is also a valid solution, simply do the same with your Tile Layers.

Comment: Yeah I think this is it. OP Don't be afraid to have multiple `useEffect` hooks — it can be a nice way to split up business logic as well (this is a good example)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a layer to your map you can do: `map.addLayer(layer);`

And if you want to remove / clean a layer before adding a new one you can `map.removeLayer(layer);`

See leaflet doc: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to make much difference - I get the same error

Comment: At this line "var map = L.map(ref.current).setView([53.9, -9.5], 10);" you initialize a new map with L.map. The error says you already have initialized one. Check that.

Comment: Yep, I think that is where the problem lies - how do I go about fixing that?

Comment: I don't use React personnaly. But if this line is the only one as a initializer for your map check if your function "useEffect" is not send many times.

Comment: ok thanks - I'll see if I can get around this somehow

Comment: You can maybe do a condition, something like if(!map) {initialize map}

Comment: Thanks - I'm still a bit lost, I've tried many things but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Initializing map');
    var map = L.map(ref.current).setView([53.9, -9.5], 10);
    setLeafletMap(map);
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {

    if(!leafletMap){ return; }

    const osm = L.tileLayer(
      'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
      {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 20,
      }
    );
      const aerial = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        {
          attribution:'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
        }
      );
        const basemapLayers = {
                'OSM': osm, 
                'Aerial': aerial
            };
        basemapLayers[selectedBasemap].addTo(leafletMap);
  }, [leafletMap, selectedBasemap]);
```

Thanks everyone